# how to display output of the javascript result on the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```html
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
```

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() {
     var query = '?';
     var str = $("form").serialize();
     $("#results").text(query += str);
     var x = $("#results").text();
     return x;
 }
  $( "input[type='sel'], input[type='text']").on( "click", myFunction);
  $( "select" ).on( "change", myFunction);

  //window.alert(myFunction());
 //query += '&' + value + '=' +  value +'.value';
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
 console.log(jsonString);
 $.ajax({
    url: 'insert_value.php',
    data: jsonString,
    
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(function(resp) {
    $('#result').html(resp)
  });
  
</script>
```

here it is not showing values of controls on console and also giving some verbose like [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. so what I should do now

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() {
     var query = '?';
     var str = $("form").serialize();
     $("#results").text(query += str);
     var x = $("#results").text();
     return x;
 }
  $( "input[type='sel'], input[type='text']").on( "click", myFunction);
  $( "select" ).on( "change", myFunction);

  //window.alert(myFunction());
 //query += '&' + value + '=' +  value +'.value';
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
 console.log(jsonString);
 $.ajax({
    url: 'insert_value.php',
    data: jsonString,
    
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(function(resp) {
    $('#result').html(resp)
    console.log('console', resp);
  });
  
</script>
```

Comment: this is coming on the console  [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.        and     on the console " console ?Gender=Male&id= " id value is not printing and if gender changes other it is not changing

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use 
console.log("your_output_here");

Comment: this is coming on the console [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. and on the console " console ?Gender=Male&id= " id value is not printing and if gender changes other it is not changing

Answer (score 0):

```js
      function myFunction() {
         var query = '?';
         var str = $("form").serialize();
         $("#results").text(query += str);
         var x = $("#results").text();
         return x;
     }
      $( "input[type='sel'], input[type='text']").on( "click", myFunction);
      $( "select" ).on( "change", myFunction);

      //window.alert(myFunction());
     //query += '&' + value + '=' +  value +'.value';
     var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
     console.log(jsonString);
     $.ajax({
        url: 'insert_value.php',
        data: jsonString,
        
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
      }).done(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
        $('#result').html(resp)
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

This is the simple snippet. this will show you output of the ajax response in the console as well as shows on the screen (div with id result). Hope this will help you..

Greetings!

Comment: no same problem nothing changing  on the console showing like this ?Gender=Male&id= and [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.    but actuall the result should be ?Gender=Female&id=704136006388169  which is query string of javascript

Comment: @Shruti Akki, can you share your insert_value.php code ?